# How to use and , or operator(&&, ||) in elasticsearch c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to search records in Nest, my conditions are, `expiration_date` can be null or it can be within some date(ex. 10-20-2018) and `effective_date` can be some date (09-20-2018).

Below is my query, here I am not able to use || and && operator, either syntax issue, or my approach is wrong, can anyone help me with this?

```
docs = await _client.SearchAsync<PriceList>(s => s.Index(config.elasticsearchIndex)

                .Query(a => a.Bool(c=>c.Should(

                    d => d.Bool(e => e.MustNot(f=>f.Exists(g => g.Field(h => h.ExpirationDate))))
                    ||
                     .Query(a => a.DateRange(r => r.Field(field => field.ExpirationDate).GreaterThanOrEquals(forThisRange.fromDate)))
                    )))

                .Query(a => a.DateRange(r => r.Field(field => field.EffectiveDate).LessThanOrEquals(forThisRange.toDate)))
```

My nest version is 6.4

UPDATED Query:

.Query(a => a.Bool(c=>c.Should(

```
                d => d.Bool(e => e.MustNot(f=>f.Exists(g => g.Field(h => h.ExpirationDate))))
                ,
                d=>d.Bool(e=>e.Must(f=>f.DateRange(r => r.Field(field => field.ExpirationDate).GreaterThanOrEquals(forThisRange.fromDate))))
                //i=>i.DateRange

                )))

            .Query(a => a.DateRange(r => r.Field(field => field.EffectiveDate).LessThanOrEquals(forThisRange.toDate)))
```

I am not getting any error, but not getting extra record,it is giving correct result + "expiration_date" has less than 10-20-2018,the later should not.

Comment: I don't dotnet, but basically you should have something like `Should(x, y)` for disjunction, where `x` is MustNot Exists, and `y` is Field GreaterThanOrEquals. Just list them all as parameters of `Should`, with commas - no `||` needed.

Comment: What's the error  you get?

Comment: @fredrik: Should be syntax error, that `||` really doesn't belong there.

Comment: @Amadan should be yes. But I'm not going to speculate, question should contain such information...

Comment: Please take a little bit of time to format your question and code correctly - having it formatted correctly will make the question much more approachable to answer :)

Comment: Not sure; can you try removing the `d=>d.Bool(...)` wrappers? I don't think they are correct. You could also use the [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html) to see what exactly is going on in Elasticsearch's brain. Also, you might translate the query into JSON, as there might be potential answerers that might know the answer but are not dotnet people (kind of like me, just better at ES :D ) and don't care to spend time decrypting the unfamiliar syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your comments.

I found the solution, replace .Query() with .PostFilter() which resolved the issue. Don't know the exact difference between them, but it worked.

If anybody knows it, please comment it, may be helpful to others.

Comment: `.Query()` and `.PostFilter()` are not the same. The latter should only be used in conjunction with aggregations, so that aggregated values are calculated _before_ further filtering documents (the use case for this is showing facets): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html